# Pause VBA from running until Excel calculated the sheet a second time

Tags: excel, vba

```
      A                B                                    C           D           E
1    Selection:        DE
2    Value 1          200  =IF($B$1="DE",100,200)
3    Value 2          100  =IF($B$1="DE",300,800)
4
5
```

In the above Excel Sheet I can enter a country in `Cell B1`. 
Based on the country the values in `Range("B2:B3")` switch accordingly as you can see in the `IF` formulas.

---

I copy the values of one country into `Range("C2:C3")` and another country into `Range("D2:D3")`. 
I use the below `VBA` to switch the country in `Cell B1` and copy the values:

```
Sub Paste_Values()
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = "DE"
Sheet1.Range("B2:B3").Copy
Sheet1.Range("C2:C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = "US"
Sheet1.Range("B2:B3").Copy
Sheet1.Range("D2:D3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

In the simple example all this works perfectly.

---

Now, I have the issue that I want to apply the same logic in a much bigger file. 
In this file I get the issue that somehow Excel calculates the `IF` formulas in `Range("B2:B3")` two times.

The **first time** it calculates `#NA` appears in the cells. 
The **second time** it displays the `correct numbers`.

However, the `VBA` does not wait until Excel calculates it a second time. 
Therefore, instead of the numbers it copies `#NA` in `Range("C2:C3")` and `Range("D2:D3")`.

Is there a way to somehow let the `VBA` wait until the numbers are displayed in `Range("B2:B3")` so it is ensured that there is no `#NA` and the `correct numbers` are copied?

Comment: You can force calculation before copying `Sheet1.Calculate`. Actually the Excel should calculate correctly the first time if there are no circles in your formulas. So I recommend to digg for the cause of that wrong calculation rather than workaround it.

Comment: Are you able to add a [mcve] of your 'larger' code so we can perhaps see what might be causing the incorrect calculation? From what you've explained I'm assuming there is something else happening with `B1` or the value in it in your 'larger' code.